# Error: You do not have permissions to use the API Calls

Tags: r, api, error-handling, redcap

I'm trying to run a code to generate a report using REDCap data. The problem is that in theory I have all the permissions for using the REDCap data, but I get this error:

**Error in redcap error(x, error_handling) : 403: ERROR: You do not permissions to use the API Calls:   ... exportMetaData -> exportMetaData.redcapApiConnection -> redcap_error**

And I don't know what is happening....

Does anybody have any idea about how to solve it?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Several layers could produce this error.  Talk to your institution's REDCap admins.

Comment: The export metadata API method might require you to have design privileges in the project, and not just data access rights. Talk to the project investigators as well as the admins. Also, you need an API token. Have you requested one?